# Access deep json link for redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, paypal

I have the following example on PayPal for HATEOS. I wanted to access the link, however having issues on my browser about a syntax error.

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list [Break On This Error]
>
> alert(links.1.href);
>
> ## (line 32, col 15)

The JSON is from paypal which I am trying to access the links

```
{
    "id": "PAY-23P72370PE379301LKIWIOTQ",
    "create_time": "2013-09-08T14:18:54Z",
    "update_time": "2013-09-08T14:18:54Z",
    "state": "created",
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "transactions": [
        {
            "amount": {
                "total": "7.47",
                "currency": "USD",
                "details": {
                    "subtotal": "7.47"
                }
            },
            "description": "payment using a PayPal account"
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-23P72370PE379301LKIWIOTQ",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-8DG907196F781211F",
            "rel": "approval_url",
            "method": "REDIRECT"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-23P72370PE379301LKIWIOTQ/execute",
            "rel": "execute",
            "method": "POST"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I access the links for the REDIRECT?

```
alert(links.1.href);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

alert(data.links[1].href);

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For accessing an array element you should use the follwing syntax:

```
alert(links[1].href);
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/skghW/